# Is it acceptable to use SoundEffectInstance for background music?

Tags: c#, audio, monogame, playback

The reason I want to do this is to be able to *layer* the background music. (e.g, simple song starts playing, player triggers something, adds an instrument). I can work out the timing issues, if any.

I thought I could do that with MediaPlayer/Song, but it wouldn't work.

All I'm really looking for is the downsides to use SoundEffectInstance.

p.s, I don't use XACT, since I'll be changing over to MonoGame eventually.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, that's what the [SoundEffectInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffectinstance.aspx) is for!

It has limitations though, depending on the platform your game is running:

> On Windows Phone, a game can have a maximum of 16 total playing
>   SoundEffectInstance instances at one time, combined across all loaded
>   SoundEffect objects. The only limit to the total number of loaded
>   SoundEffectInstance and SoundEffect objects is available memory.
>   However, the user can play only 16 sound effects at one time. Attempts
>   to play a SoundEffectInstance beyond this limit will fail. On Windows,
>   there is no hard limit. Playing too many instances can lead to
>   performance degradation. On Xbox 360, the limit is 300 sound effect
>   instances loaded or playing. Dispose of old instances if you need
>   more.

Oh and  by the way, it's been a long time since I played with XNA but I'm pretty sure that the XACT tool was no longer necessary by the end of it's life cycle. 
I seem to recall that you could load an mp3 on the Content folder and play it via the `SoundEffectInstance` object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I just tried using .mp3 format for SoundEffect/SoundEffectInstance, didn't work. Though I can just convert .mp3 to .wav, so I don't think it's a big deal. Also thanks for the sound effect limit info. I have an Ambience2D class which is constantly playing nearby ambience effects. If I intend to do mobile/console releases, I'll have to keep that in mind. (I'm assuming since there is no limit on Windows, there isn't a limit on other desktop platforms (Monogame-wise)).

Comment: I don't think this is actually what it's for.  SoundEffectInstance sits in memory uncompressed so that it can be played immediately.  Because of this it occupes a *lot* of space relative to MP3's.  The music class decompresses and streams as necessary, greatly reducing the amount of RAM used up.  I'd say "it depends" but I wouldn't default to using uncompressed SoundEffects for music.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think you'll find using the [MediaPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.aspx) class combined with the [Song](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.song.aspx) class is the recommended way to play background music.

> Provides methods and properties to play, pause, resume, and stop songs. MediaPlayer also exposes shuffle, repeat, volume, play position, and visualization capabilities.

I *think* the primary difference is that the MediaPlayer can stream the data into memory rather than loading it all in at once. So, for long playing music tracks this is the way to go.

Also, in MonoGame these classes are implemented by wrapping around the platform specific classes that do the same thing. For example, on Android the SoundEffectInstance uses the Android SoundPool (intended for sound effects) and the MediaPlayer uses the Android MediaPlayer (intended for music). See [this post](https://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/540073) on the MonoGame forums for reference.

> slygamer says: MediaPlayer for background music and SoundEffect for sound effects is how it is designed to be used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I said in my post, I wanted to be able to layer the different instruments and activate them at different locations in a map. I tried using MediaPlayer + Song for this, though with MediaPlayer being static, it could only play one song at a time. I've already tested the code using SoundEffectInstance, and it works great so far.

Comment: No problem. I was my fault for answering the title of your question without properly reading the detail. Anyway, I think this information will still be useful to others. Cheers.